# Does Super User have a "could not be reproduced" vote reason?

Tags: support, close-reasons

My primary hunting grounds Ask Ubuntu, Unix & Linux and Vi and Vim have a "could not reproduced" close reason (or something close enough). Does Super User have something similar? I know I can only flag, but the close reasons would be available for me too, right? How does SU handle such questions?

Specifically with regards to [Ulimit is set on second login, not first](https://superuser.com/questions/793136/ulimit-is-set-on-second-login-not-first?noredirect=1#comment1445781_793136)

Comment: I feel it might be important to point out that before you say something cannot be reproduced in a flag to the moderators with the intention of getting a question closed.  Be sure your attempting to reproduce it on the same version the author of a question is using.  Otherwise the question won't be closed, just because the question is old, does not mean it cannot be answered or the issue cannot be reproduced.  In the end the user did have a problem.

Comment: @Ramhound for that specific question, the OP said things have started working fine. I couldn't reproduce anyway.

Comment: I was giving general advice.  Since the only answer is to flag it, with a custom reason, which would be present to other people reviewing the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Does Super User have something similar to "could not reproduced"?

Super User does not have that specific close reason as you have noticed.

**If you have 3000+ rep**

You can Vote to Close then do the following:

- Close > Off-topic because > Other > Comment: "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is no longer reproducible and the question is not likely to be useful for future visitors"

Or:

- Flag > Should be closed > Off-topic because > Other > Comment: "I'm voting
  to close this question as off-topic because the problem is no longer
  reproducible and the question is not likely to be useful for future
  visitors"

**If you have between 20 and 3000 rep**

As per the comment by [Ben N](https://meta.superuser.com/users/380318/ben-n) a rep of 3000+ is need to use the "Other" reason.

As per the comment by [CanadianLuke](https://meta.superuser.com/users/24010/canadian-luke) you can visit the Super User Chat Room ([Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access)) if you have 20+ rep and ask there.

- There are lots of regulars in [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) that can VTC as appropriate.

Comment: Unfortunately flagging for users without enough privileges doesn't include custom reasons: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iHeiW.png :/. Anyway, I guess others will handle that question now that I have bought some attention to it.

Comment: @muru Ah. It's a long time since I didn't have a lot of rep ;). Thanks for pointing that out. I wonder how much rep is needed?

Comment: @DavidPostill It changes at the transition from flagging to close to voting to close, that is, at 3K. For sub-3K, that slot is taken by "blatantly off-topic."

Comment: @BenN Thanks. Answer updated.

Comment: @CanadianLuke Good point. Added to answer.